# Filtering Results of Observable Before Subscribing in Angular App

Tags: javascript, angular, eventemitter, angular2-observables

I have a situation where I'm using Output() and EventEmitter() to pass down an event in my Angular app from one component to another. I'm actually passing this event down twice - because three components are involved.

Then, when the event is received from the component that needs to respond, I am using this function:

```
optionReceived(option, page) {
    console.log('Consulting page # is: ' + option.toolbarLabel);
    if (option.toolbarLabel && option.toolbarLabel === 'OT') {
        this.clientService.getByStage('consulting', 1, this.pagesize)
            .subscribe(resRecordsData => {
                this.records = resRecordsData;
                this.page = page;
                console.log(this.records);
            },
            responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError);
        }
}
```

This works as expected. However, what I really want to be able to here is filter these results based on the parameter that is passed in via the click event that's been handled by the Output() and EventEmitter(). So, all that is to say, really I want to have the **exact same function as above**, but with a filter applied, so it looks like this:

```
optionReceived(option, page) {
    console.log('Consulting page # is: ' + option.toolbarLabel);
    if (option.toolbarLabel && option.toolbarLabel === 'OT') {
        this.clientService.getByStage('consulting', 1, this.pagesize)
            .filter(resRecordsData => resRecordsData.type && resRecordsData.type === 'OT')
            .subscribe(resRecordsData => {
                this.records = resRecordsData;
                this.page = page;
                console.log(this.records);
            },
            responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError);
        }
}
```

Right now this is not working. When this function is triggered I get the console.log I would expect from above, but new results are not generated. I don't get an error - it's just that the data doesn't change based on the filter.

What's the issue here? Without any errors it's difficult to know where the issue lies.

By the way, my imports look like this:

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { ClientService } from '../../../data/client.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using rxjs observables?

Comment: I am using rxjs observables.

Comment: Have you import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter'?

Comment: Please share your import statements

Comment: rxjs operators needs to be imported in order for them to work

Comment: Just added them above.

Comment: If you add `.do((log) => console.log(log))` before `.filter()` are you getting anything, and if so should the object pass the filter expression (`resRecordsData.type && resRecordsData.type === 'OT'`)?

Comment: Also, does .getByStage return an array? Filter in rxjs does not work the same as filter in regular javascript.

Comment: Yes, getByStage returns an array. And "records" is initiated as an empty array in the component.

Comment: Ok that's your problem. Let me type out an answer for you.

Comment: If I understood you wanted to filter the array before subscription, but still subscribe. Now if there are no records with type = OT you will still get an empty array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using rxjs `filter` as you would have used it in javascript.

Filter in this case just unwraps the observable and stop the stream if a certain condition fails, it will not iterate over each item in your array unless you intruct it to.

To filter your array prior to subscription use the `map` operator:

```
.map(resRecordsData => {
  let data = resRecordsData.data.filter(item => item.gender && item.gender === 'male');
  resRecordsData['data'] = data;
  resRecordsData['count'] = data.length;
  return resRecordsData
})
```

Also do not forget to import it:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

Comment: I will try this, thanks. And to clarify, you mean replace the filter line with this .map line, yes?

Comment: Correct, use `filter` if you for whatever reason does not want the subscription to happen.

Comment: Tried it. Unfortunately it's still not working. But it occurs to me, perhaps the issue is that at the point .map is called, it doesn't know it's working on an array. And that may have been the case with .filter as well. Because only AFTER the .map and the .filter is "resRecordsData" set equal to "records". Thoughts?

Comment: Can you share the results you get if you add this just before the map operator: `.do((log) => console.log(log))` if that works as expected then so should the map part.

Comment: When I add that I get this printed to the console: Object {count: 4037, data: Array(12)}

Comment: To clarify, the "Object {count: 4037, data: Array(12)}" is the same collection that was returned as before it was filtered or mapped over.

Comment: Hm. There were an err in my code, but that will not fix this. Where are you getting your type-property from? It appears as the results from .getByStage is an Object and not an Array.

Comment: You're right that it's an object with an array inside. And in my view I'm using "*ngFor records of records.data" because "data" is actually the array within the object.

Comment: Ok I get it, if you run the map with the current revision are you getting the results you want?

Comment: With the answer you provided using .map, it doesn't return different results. Just like .filter didn't. So for some reason neither 'filter' nor 'map' seem to be working here. Perhaps the issue is that "records" is not declared until AFTER the .map or .filter?

Comment: Yes you definitely need that. `resRecordsData.data.filter` filters your array within the object. If you are not getting the filtered results I need to see how the objects look like inside your array. You can do that with: .do((log) => console.log(JSON.stringify(log)))

Comment: The records in the data property are definitely there: Object {count: 4037, data: _Array(12)_ } if you are not getting the filtered results it's because the expression fails

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142008/discussion-between-unitario-and-muirik).

Comment: No, those records are the same as from BEFORE the call was made. In other words, the results are unchanged.

Comment: However... I'm getting closer, when I tried this:
 .map((resRecordsData) => resRecordsData.data.filter((item) => resRecordsData.data.gender === 'female'))
... I got an empty array. So at least I'm getting an array. Now need to figure out why it's empty.